# Simple post request to get location

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I am trying to get the location of a user and send it to my server so I can make some api calls. I get the current location of the user, which is fine, but it does not post to the server and I do not know why. Can you look at my code and help me figure it out.

**Backend**

*index.routes.js*

```
router.post('/currentLatLong', ctrlEvent.currentLatLong);
```

*event.controller.js*

```
module.exports.currentLatLong = (req, res) => {
  console.log('recieved');
  this.currentLoc = req.body;
  console.log('this.currentLoc', this.currentLoc);
}
```

**Front-end**

*Service*

```
    constructor(private data: DataService, private http: HttpClient) { }

    getUserLocation() {
    /* locate the User */
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.currentLng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('position.coords.latitude', this.currentLat);
        this.data.latitudeSource.next(this.currentLat);
        this.data.longitudeSource.next(this.currentLng);
        const currentLatLong = {
          latitude: this.currentLat,
          longitude: this.currentLng
        };
        console.log('currentLatLong', currentLatLong);
        return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/currentLatLong', 
        currentLatLong);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      });
      } else {
      console.log('bad');
      return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any console.log output from the `event.controller.js` snippet?

Comment: @ulmas no thats where the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular side, you need to call the `subscribe()` method. Calling the `subscribe()` method executes the observable, which is what initiates the request.

```
this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/currentLatLong', currentLatLong)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method.

Comment: Sorry one more question, do you know why this variable will not get assigned in express when i try to assign it globally ```let currentLoc;

module.exports.currentLatLong = (req, res) => {
  console.log('recieved', req.body);
  this.currentLoc = req.body;
  console.log('this.currentLoc', this.currentLoc);
} ```

Comment: can you try just currentLoc instead of this.currentLoc? Or do you want to learn the reason why this.currentLoc doesn't work?

Comment: Is there no "this" in express?

Comment: Of course there is this expressjs (more truely in nodejs), but in this case, currentLoc is just a variable. this is meaningfull in a class